# Which tool do I have to use for wire connector?

Tags: connector, wire, tools

I want to make the wire connector as the screen below. What tool do I need to use and how can I make it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that is a [Molex Spox](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=spox&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_wire_connectors) connector. The connectors are crimped on the wire leads and snapped into place in the connector head.